# neo4j bulk insert using cypher

Tags: neo4j

How do i insert the following into neo4j

```
create (st:serviceticket {name:'SRT_519'}) 
with st as st 
match (st:serviceticket) where st.name='SRT_519' 
match (d:ProductID) where d.name ='PRD_1014'
with st as st , d as d 
merge (d)-[:SERVICE_TICKETID]->(st);


create (st:serviceticket {name:'SRT_520'}) 
with st as st 
match (st:serviceticket) where st.name='SRT_520'
match (d:ProductID) where d.name ='PRD_1004'
with st as st , d as d 
merge (d)-[:SERVICE_TICKETID]->(st);
```

if i am having multiple records like this to insert how can i insert  all of them at a shot.Please help me.

Comment: Where is your data(SRT_519, PRD_1014) coming from? A file or another db or?

Comment: PRD_1014 nodes like that i have created already and now to those nodes i need to add the nodes like SRT_519 with a relation

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume that nodes for your products already exist.

Remember that your "st" is a reference and you are trying to assign the same reference twice in one batch.
The first step is to give your service tickets separate references

```
match (d:ProductID), (e:ProductID)
where d.name ='PRD_1014'and
e.name ='PRD_1004'
create (st519:serviceticket {name:'SRT_519'}) 
create (st520:serviceticket {name:'SRT_520'}) 


merge (d)-[:SERVICE_TICKETID]->(st519)
merge (e)-[:SERVICE_TICKETID]->(st520)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use parameters, you can provide an array of pairs:

you should have an index or constraint on :ServiceTicket(name) and :ProductID(name)

```
WITH [['SRT_519','PRD_1014']] as data
FOREACH (pair in data |
    MERGE (st:ServiceTicket {name:data[0]}),(d:ProductID {name:data[1]})
    MERGE (d)-[:SERVICE_TICKETID]->(st);
)
```